# Missing Constraint when opening Android Device Monitor

Tags: android, eclipse

When launching [`monitor`](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monitor.html), it crashes and writes the following to its log file:

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The bundle "org.eclipse.core.runtime_3.8.0.v20120912-155025 [44]" could not be resolved. Reason: Missing Constraint: Bundle-    RequiredExecutionEnvironment: CDC-1.0/Foundation-1.0,J2SE-1.3
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolverError(AbstractBundle.java:1332)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolutionFailureException(AbstractBundle.java:1316)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:323)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1176)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.common 4 0 2016-03-18 10:50:26.908
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The bundle "org.eclipse.equinox.common_3.6.100.v20120522-1841 [83]" could not be resolved. Reason: Missing Constraint: Bundle-  RequiredExecutionEnvironment: CDC-1.1/Foundation-1.1,J2SE-1.4
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolverError(AbstractBundle.java:1332)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolutionFailureException(AbstractBundle.java:1316)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:323)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1176)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2016-03-18 10:50:26.964
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime_3.8.0.v20120912-155025.jar was not resolved.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2016-03-18 10:50:26.965
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.common_3.6.100.v20120522-1841.jar was not resolved.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2016-03-18 10:50:26.968
!MESSAGE Could not start bundle: org.eclipse.equinox.console
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not start bundle: org.eclipse.equinox.console
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.ConsoleManager.checkForConsoleBundle(ConsoleManager.java:217)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startup(EclipseStarter.java:297)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:176)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:520)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The bundle "org.eclipse.equinox.console_1.0.0.v20120522-1841 [84]" could not be resolved. Reason: Missing Constraint: Bundle-    RequiredExecutionEnvironment: J2SE-1.5
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolverError(AbstractBundle.java:1332)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolutionFailureException(AbstractBundle.java:1316)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:323)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.ConsoleManager.checkForConsoleBundle(ConsoleManager.java:215)
    ... 9 more
Root exception:
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The bundle "org.eclipse.equinox.console_1.0.0.v20120522-1841 [84]" could not be resolved. Reason: Missing Constraint: Bundle-   RequiredExecutionEnvironment: J2SE-1.5
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolverError(AbstractBundle.java:1332)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolutionFailureException(AbstractBundle.java:1316)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:323)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.ConsoleManager.checkForConsoleBundle(ConsoleManager.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startup(EclipseStarter.java:297)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:176)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:520)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
```

I'm running Java 7 on Mac OSX 10.9.5:

```
$ java -version
  java version "1.7.0_71"
```

Comment: looks like an Eclipse error. I would probably reinstall Eclipse

Comment: This is Android Device Monitor, which seems to use Eclipse plugins. I don't have Eclipse installed, nor is it a prerequisite to using this tool

Comment: @AmandeepGrewal Probably the same problem here. Have you found a solution?

Comment: Same problem on Linux with Android Studio and the Android Device Monitor

Comment: I had similar issues on Linux and I had to install the oracle Java 8

Comment: same issue on Mac OSX 10.12.6 with *only* java 9 (9.0.1) installed

Comment: same problem here today :( 2018 and still found no answer

Comment: I had same issue on Mac OS 10.13.6

Answer (score 2):

I found this and it works: https://gist.github.com/sshnakamoto/074b5428a25b467e4402d97ded02be9d

> 1. Run command:
>
> `/usr/libexec/java_home -V` Results should look like:
>
> ```
> 9.0.4, x86_64:    "Java SE 9.0.4" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.0.4.jdk/Contents/Home
> 1.8.0_144, x86_64:    "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home
> ```
>
> 2. If you see a Java 9 in result then disable:
>
> First navigate to
>   `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.0.4.jdk/Contents/` Then rename
>   `Info.plist` -> `Info.disabled.plist`
>
> 3. Verify Java 9 is disabled:
>
> Re-run `/usr/libexec/java_home -V` and you should no longer see Java 9
>   version listed

For me, there was a Java 11.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work by deleting Java 9 and installing Java 8

On a mac I ran this

> sudo rm -rf /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.0.1.jdk
>   sudo rm -rf /Library/PreferencePanes/JavaControlPanel.prefPane
>   sudo rm -rf /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin

Then install Java 8

> brew cask install caskroom/versions/java8

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get Android Monitor (as part of VisualStudio for Mac) start again by editing:

```
<user's>/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx/tools/lib/monitor-x86_64/monitor.app/Contents/Info.plist
```

And uncommenting one of the lines under the line saying:

```
> to use a specific Java version (instead of the platform's default)
> uncomment one of the following options
```

And added a line containing the path to an older JDK/JRE version on the machine. In my case JDK 1.8. Which looks like:

```
<string>-vm</string><string>/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java</string>
```